# VSCode Code Runner is faster than running the code directly on my Linux terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, time.h, vscode-code-runner

I have this basic CSV search substring algorithm that I am working on and I am measuring the performance between running it on my raspberry pi 4 terminal vs doing it on CodeRunner. My CodeRunner is running much faster than doing this in terminal `./performanceTest` I am wondering if CodeRunner is not even running on my Pi since I am sshing into it? This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void TP_4091() {
    FILE* stream = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    if (!stream) {
        printf("Error occured");
    }
    struct timespec tstart = {0, 0}, tend = {0, 0};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tstart);
    char searchCharacter[] = "New York";
    char buf[1024]; // storing the first 1024 lines into a buffer
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stream)) {
        char *token;

        token = strtok(buf, ",");

        while(token != NULL) {
            if (strstr(token, "New York") != NULL) {
                printf("%s ", buf);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tend);
    long ttotal = tend.tv_nsec - tstart.tv_nsec;
    printf("Time taken to run the function in normal C: %lu\n", ttotal);
    fclose(stream);
}

int main(void *ctx)
{
    TP_4091();
}
```

Here is the time I received from when I ran it on CodeRunner here, 68018, and here is the time I got from `./performanceTest`, 252627. The reason I am using clock_gettime is that there is a BPF equivalent that allows me to compare BPF performance, no other reason why.

Comment: I am not an expert on `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, but are you sure that the clock frequency is sufficient? Are you sure that `tv_sec` is zero, I thought that it is an unspecified start point?

Comment: How big is the file?  What order did your run your tests in?  How many times did you run your tests?  How do you know that the `tv_sec` field value in both `tend` and `tstart` have the same value so that merely subtracting the `tv_nsec` fields is sufficient?

Comment: You have a lot of printfs in your timed block. The time taken for these can vary greatly, depending on buffering, output redirection, size of the console window, and other factors.

Comment: This might be a good inspiration of why I decided to do it this way calculate the elapsed time: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_418.html. I mean it's running the same code, so wouldn't the numbers be similar to an extent? I ran my code around 10-12 times. Running it on my terminal nets me a value as high as 492762 but it's usually within 220000-270000. CodeRunner seems to be more or less consistent with the numbers I have been receiving. Should I use another metric to confirm?

Comment: "... it's running the same code.." How do you conclude that? The code in your link has conditionals and corrections using math operations. You're doing a simple subtraction with the nanoseconds. Aside from completely ignoring whole seconds, it's possible your math could come out negative. Imagine `tstart` is 1sec, 750M nanoseconds, and `tend` is 2sec, 250M nanoseconds. That whole operation took half a second, but your math will say it took -500M nanoseconds. You must account for whole seconds and the nanosecond wraparound.

Comment: "You must account for whole seconds and the nanosecond wraparound," Could you expand more into this? I am not really sure how I can make sure this problem is mitigated. Do you have an example aswell?

Comment: Ever seen a digital clock? There are hours, minutes, and seconds fields. Hours range from [1,12], min and sec range from [0,59]. When the sec reach 59, the next +1 _wraps around_ the field to 0 and the min are incremented. If the mins are at 59 when the +1 happens, that field _wraps around_ to 0 and the hours are incremented.. and so on. That's exactly what's happening here, except with seconds and nanoseconds. `tv_nsec` ranges from [0 to 999,999,999]. The next +1 wraps around that field to 0 and `tv_sec` is incremented by one. You must consider both fields when calculating elapsed time.